# IWebBrowserDisp ole2 interface cannot open IE window to front of the screen

Tags: delphi, delphi-4

With Windows 7/8,  this very nice ole2 interface IWebBrowserDisp is no more working properly, for some reason it now opens the IExplorer Window behind the actual currently running delphi application, not to the front of the screen as it used to be work earlier.

This makes the application to fail as user cannot see the opening web page without manually switching to Iexplorer and locating the correct window.

The code that I use to launch the link is:

```
  WB : TEmbeddedWB;
  wb.Navigate(URL,x,x,x,x);
```

This problem does not exist in older  Windows or while   I use my Delphi IDE  ( I use Delphi4 and run it as ADMIN).

Comment: Are you referring to links that open document in a new window? (such as target=_blank)? I cant reproduce this with Win7/Delphi5.

Comment: Foreground activation permission is like love: You can't steal it, it has to be given to you http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/02/20/9435239.aspx

Comment: Yes, I use new Window (_top) Should I use CoAllowSetForegroundWindow somehow from Delphi to allow IE to be foreground?

Comment: why don't you open the popup window in your own application? You already host a TEmbeddedWB...

Comment: I fail to see how "_top" should open up in a new window.